# Website on IIS server takes 10-15mins to load

Tags: php, iis, server, loading, fastcgi

I have a big website with many visitors daily. When I get a large increase in visitors my website keeps loading for 10-15 minutes (for a long time).

This is not a DoS attack, I have figured it out. It's something with IIS PHP, because I see many (100+ fastcgi.exe) php fastcgi.exe processes in the task manager.

My RAM and CPU are fine, I have 128GB RAM. I use now 8-9 GB ram.

I think that the website script is loading for ever and get stuck. Has IIS a setting to set the script running higher? I have checked my logs and can now see this:

> The FastCGI process has failed frequently recently

I am using Windows Server 2008, but can replicate this behaviour on Windows Server 2012 also. I'm using Wincache for the opcode cache.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Are you using an opcode cache? Does this problem manifest itself for all visitors? Does it behave like this across all browsers? Does the problem go away temporarily if you restart the IIS service in the Windows control panel?

Comment: I use PHP version 5.3.28. I have this problem in all php versions. I use wincache. After that i restart the IIS server the website still keeps loading. The problem is go away when there are not (many) visitors anymore.

Comment: I don't use IIS, but you've not added a lot of detail, so there's not much to go on. Edit: ah, is Wincache your opcode cache? I am not familiar with it. Does this produce any logs of its own?

Comment: What is in your logs? Does IIS offer a debugging mode so you can see more detail here? Is switching to Apache an option for you?

Comment: Is there anything in your Windows system logs? (A site of this level of traffic, I would say almost _certainly_ has something of interest).

Comment: @halfer Do you have skype? My logs have IP's included. Its huge.

Comment: Just trim out the IP addresses from the logs, maybe using a regexp replace (good thinking not to publish them!) and then you can add a sample here. (We try to discourage private support on Stack Overflow, since it usually results in the answer to the problem being lost. If everything can be presented on this page, someone in the future may well benefit from it).

Comment: As for what logs to look out for, I don't know; I don't use Windows. I expect there will be log levels (error, warning, notice, etc - check the most severe ones first).

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?

Comment: @halfer I use windows 2008 server. Before i have used windows 2012 but the problem is there also. There are no errors in the files the website is only keeps loading.

Comment: Now i get this error: The FastCGI process has failed frequently recently. Try the request again in a while

Comment: OK, that sounds like something [you can research](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+iis+php+The+FastCGI+process+has+failed+frequently+recently) - and there [are a couple more here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+FastCGI+process+has+failed+frequently+recently) too.

Comment: @halfer I have fixed this error, but the website is still keeps loading for ever. Can you give me please your skype? When its fixed i will write a report how you haved help me with it.

Comment: I should have mentioned another reason why I try to discourage such requests - asking for community help in public is fine, but requiring dedicated one-on-one support generally means you need a freelancer (i.e. people don't wish to work for free). I probably won't be much help anyway, for the reasons already stated - I try not to use Microsoft products (including Skype `:-)`).

Comment: If you are really stuck, you could swap to Apache? I hear it runs quite well on Windows these days.

Comment: I understand that. Apache is not a alternative for me. Because al mine files are writed in PHP (.php) so Apache is not a solution. I already have set the fastcgi settings higher but without results. Maybe you have another idea? @halfer

Comment: Eh? Apache runs PHP very well indeed, on all platforms as far as I know. It is _possible_ that you must use IIS, but I've not seen a plausible reason from you yet. Are you sure you are locked into it?

Comment: @halfer Good news, i have checked all the logs and i saw a couple of IP's connnecting many times in a couple of seconds. So i have done research and saw my website was really under DDos attack.

Comment: Mine hosting told me that i'm was not underattack.  I have now a server in a protected network. (Anti-ddos) Anyways thanks for help me much! @halfer.